# Powershell UDP Port Test script [System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient]

Tags: powershell

when attempting to run my UDP Port test script then I got the following the error message. How can I fix this?

Error Message:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient] does not contain a method named 'BeginConnect'.
At line:12 char:9
+         $connect = $obj.BeginConnect($target,$port,$null,$null)
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Script :

```
$targetservers = "192.168.2.2"
$ports = "53"

$result = @()

foreach ($target in $targetservers) {

    foreach ($port in $ports) {

        $obj = new-Object System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient

        $connect = $obj.BeginConnect($target,$port,$null,$null)

        $Wait = $connect.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(100,$false)

        If (-Not $Wait) {

            write-host $target ‘port’ $port ‘Closed – Timeout’

        }

        else {

            $value = “Open”

            write-host $target ‘port’ $port $value

            $r = new-object -type psobject

            $r | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name host -value $target

            $r | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name port -value $port

            $r | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name state -value $value

            $result += $r

        }

    }

}
```

UPDATE 1:

```
$targetservers = "192.168.200.11"
$ports = "53"

$result = @()

foreach ($target in $targetservers) {

    foreach ($port in $ports) {

        $obj = new-Object System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient

        $connect = $obj.Connect($target,$port)

        $Wait = $connect.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(100,$false)

        If (-Not $Wait) {

            write-host $target ‘port’ $port ‘Closed – Timeout’

        }

        else {

            $value = “Open”

            write-host $target ‘port’ $port $value

            $r = new-object -type psobject

            $r | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name host -value $target

            $r | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name port -value $port

            $r | add-member -membertype noteproperty -name state -value $value

            $result += $r

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: The error is quite clear: the UDP client doesn't contain a method BeginConnect (this is because you can't really connect with UDP, it's more like fire and forget). You can use BeginSend, BeginReceive etc

Comment: Now I have tried different class. (`$connect = $obj.Connect($target,$port)`) But I am getting different error message. I have updated my question.

Comment: UdpClient inherits the Socket Class.  The BeginConnect is in the property Client (the socket).  So use $obj.Client.BeginConnect().  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?view=net-7.0#properties

Comment: `.Connect` is a synchronous operation, there is no such thing as a `.AsyncWaitHandle` for a sync op.

Comment: You can't test UDP without using a client-server architecture because UDP doesn't send responses. You can see implementation of the client-server architecture in Powershell, for example, [here](https://cloudbrothers.info/en/test-udp-connection-powershell/)

Comment: @jdweng according to the Microsoft documentation UDPClient doesn't inherit from socket. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient?view=net-7.0

Comment: The socket properties are definitely in the Client property.  Try it.

Comment: @jdweng having a socket as a datatype on a property isn't the same as inheritence.